# Define a function in a python module so that the function name equals to a string variable

Tags: python

I have a python module which expected to expose an function with configurable name.

**module.py** looks like this:

```
def _actual_func():
    print "do the actual work"

INTERFACE_NAME = _load_interface_name_from_conf()

if INTERFACE_NAME == 'foo':
    def foo():
        _actual_func()
elif INTERFACE_NAME == 'bar':
    def bar():
        _actual_func()
elif INTERFACE_NAME == 'baz':
    def baz():
        _actual_func()
```

The client uses my module like this:

```
import module

# call the interface function
FUNCTION_NAME_TO_CALL = _load_form_client_conf() # configured to equal INTERFACE_NAME
getattr(module, FUNCTION_NAME_TO_CALL)()
```

The problem is the code can only work when `INTERFACE_NAME` equals `'foo'`, `'bar'` or `'baz'`.
How can I rewrite my code so that I can configure the `INTERFACE_NAME` to any string value?

Comment: I'm really curious what the use-case for this is.

Comment: @kaya3 I actually have multiple clients using my module with different naming protocol (It is difficult for them to change protocol due to historical reason). For example, one of them just call **foo()** and another just call **bar()**, I do not want to publish a different code for each of my client, I want a configurable solution.

Comment: Interesting. If it's just one function, could the clients write `from your_module import your_func_name as their_func_name`? If there are many functions with configurable names, they could write a "wrapper" module with multiple `import ... as ...` statements, and then import that wrapper module instead of importing your module directly.

Comment: @kaya3 Unfortunately, each client has a protocol that generates a list of method names, all function name is generated by the protocol code. If I let my clients make adjustment, each of them really need a remapping logic so that they finally map to a same protocol, and this will be way too costly. To simplify the question and make it clear, I just put a single function in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setattr`.  You will need `sys` to get the module corresponding to your own module:

```
import sys

def _actual_func():
    print("do the actual work")

INTERFACE_NAME = _load_interface_name_from_conf()
_thismodule = sys.modules[__name__]
setattr(_thismodule, INTERFACE_NAME, _actual_func)
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I know that I can update ```sys.modules[__name__]```. After some test, I found updating ```locals()``` also works. Is there any difference between the two methods?

Comment: I don't know - see the documentation.  It's just that if your callers are going to call `getattr`, using `setattr` seems the most obvious answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do simpler by eval() function.

```
def foo():
    pass
def bar():
    pass

def call_func(name):   
    eval(name + "()")

call_func("foo")
call_func("bar")
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem; the names the module exports will not include the name given in the string variable.